# pass function as parameter to a method

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to write a simple class which initializes openGL. I decided to create method `run` where I initialize opengl, glutDisplayFunc, glutMainLoop. 
I want to pass draw function to this method and use it as a parameter for `glutDisplayFunc`

```
void OpenGL::run(void(*drawFunction())) {
    this->init();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawFunction);
    glutMainLoop();
};
```

But I've got an error `argument of void type *(*)() is incompatible with parameter of type void (*)()`.

It does not work `glutDisplayFunc(&drawFunction);` and `glutDisplayFunc(*drawFunction);` either.
What's the problem?

Comment: typedef void (*callback_function)(void);
void OpenGL::run(callback_function param)

Comment: Hust a hint: GLUT doesn't work well with being encapsulated in classes. If you really want to use a class for your main application structure, you should write a number of GLUT wrapper functions that forward the callbacks to the main application object. However I strongly suggest you overthink the whole "app class" approach. By definition there can be only one application instance in a given program. Which means that that application class will always be used as (if it were) a singleton. Singletons however are regarded an anti pattern by many people http://goo.gl/zU43IF – so why use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misplaced a closing parenthesis:

```
void OpenGL::run(void (*drawFunction)()) {
```

Function pointers then act like any other pointers, you just pass them by value. You're already doing that correctly: `glutDisplayFunc(drawFunction);`

The documentation for `glutDisplayFunc` also show the prototype of the callback: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html

Comment: and for `glutDisplayFunc` it will be `glutDisplayFunc(drawFunction);` or `glutDisplayFunc(*drawFunction);`?

Comment: `glutDisplayFunc(drawFunction);` Just like you have in your question.

Comment: and if your drafunction is another member then add __closure before *